# does os based certificates (ca-bundle.crt) work fine using smtp_tls_CAfile

Tags: ssl, smtp, certificate, local

Is it compulsory to use:

1. smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

While I'm also using:

1. smtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/videoshark.io/fullchain.pem
2. smtp_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/videoshark.io/privkey.pem

I mean whats the difference in both?

This is the error Im seeing when I RUN: tail /var/log/maillog
postfix/smtpd[1419]: fatal: open lock file pid/inet.smtp: cannot open file: Permission denied

I just want postfix to be configured with gmail relay service using SSL/TLS
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`smtp_tls_cert_file` and `smtp_tls_key_file` are to specify the local certificate, i.e. the one which gets provided to the SMTP client inside the TLS handshake. This is therefore needed if you want to accept TLS traffic.

`smtp_tls_CAfile` is to verify the certificate Postfix gets when communicating with another mail server. This is therefore needed if you want it to be able to use TLS when sending mail to other servers.

Comment: so when i want to use postfix for gmail smtp relay to send messages via gmail I can only go with smtp_tls_CAfile and one more thing is there any change required in cert file before I use it in main.cf?

Comment: @Rehan: *"when i want to use postfix for gmail smtp relay to send messages via gmail I can only go with smtp_tls_CAfile"* - correct, if your Postfix should not accept mails via TLS then you don't need to set a cert and key and CA is enough. *"is there any change required in cert file before I use it in main.cf?"* - I have no idea what you mean by this but it looks like a different question and thus should be asked as a new question and not in a comment.